# Arithmetic with concurrent_vector iterators: is it safe to assume that subtracting 'begin ()' from an iterator will give the index?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, concurrency, iterator

Since the concurrent_vector does not use a contiguous memory block, I would just like to be sure of whether this is okay:

```
concurrency::concurrent_vector<Something> my_array;

//Populate 'm_array' somehow perhaps involving multiple threads

const auto iter  = std::find_if (my_array.begin (), m_array.end (), SomeLambda);
const int  index = iter - my_array.begin ();
```

My question: Are there any cases where 'index' will not index the element that I've just found (via the concurrect_vector::operator[] method)?  I realise that another thread could theoretically modify the element - that is not my question.

I guess this ought to work, but because I'm used to working with raw pointers, I would just like to ask (so that I don't inadvertently add a source of subtle bugs).

Comment: And what is `concurent_vector`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355343.aspx ?

Comment: It has a `difference_type`, and the documentation says it is a random access iterator, so assuming MS are sane and following [The Standard meaning of that phrase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), this is safe.

Comment: Thanks @BoBTFish.  That's a helpful reference.

Comment: Microsoft's `concurrent_vector` was derived from tbb's `concurrent_vector`.  If you need to port your code to something not windows you can pretty much drop the tbb implementation in without change: http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_vector.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concurrent_vector::iterator` is a random access iterator, so taking the difference is supported and valid (although you shouldn't be using an `int` to store the result).

Of course, as you note, that's not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks @Joe.  I'll go ahead and write my code on the basis of this answer.  Thanks for amending the question too - I hadn't realised that the concurrent_vector was Microsoft-specific, but that's still fine as I only write code in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Coder_Dan It doesn't appear to be adding a lot to `std::vector`. You could write this functionality quite easily if you wanted portable code. Having said that, someone else has probably done it already.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe, but why not use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) anyway?

- It's more idiomatic.
- It will work if you change containers.
- It's just as efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Alex.  I'm a relative newcomer to STL, and hadn't come across std::distance before.